# Помогите разобраться с фyнкцией register_next_step_handler. Библиотека: pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, бот, telebot

Я читал вопросы на этy темy, но немного не понял как строить с ней цепи, и для чего аргyмент message. И как сделать с ней рекyрсию. Пример: Введите число, если ввели не число, то обратно пишет Введите число.

Comment: вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введите число')  # сообщение от бота
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)  # регистрация след.шага, отправка сообщения, переход к след.функции


def start_2(message):
    if message.text.isdigit():  # если сообщение от пользователя число
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ваше число {}'.format(message.text))  # отправка сообщения пользователю
    else:  # иначе (если не число)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'это не число')  # отправка сообщения пользователю
        start(message)  # переход к функции
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы знаете как сделать чтобы из этого цилка можно было выйти?

Comment: в `def start_2` под `if` добавьте, к примеру, `elif message.text == 'отмена':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'на нет и суда нет')`